# Necessary and Sufficient Condition for Existence of Isomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}_{nm}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_n\bigoplus \mathbb{Z}_m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory, abelian-groups

It is known that when $\gcd(n,m) = 1$, there exists an isomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}_{nm}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_n\bigoplus \mathbb{Z}_m$. This is the Chinese remainder theorem.

However, I am required to give a necessary and sufficient condition such that such an isomorphism exists. I conjectured that this is true if and only if $\gcd(n,m) = 1$, but I am not able to prove this. Is my claim correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  Prove it by contradiction by examining orders of elements.

Comment: @Randall By orders of elements do you mean x^k for some integer k?

Comment: Well, yes, but in additive notation given your context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $d:=\gcd(m,n)$ 
and 
let $D:=\dfrac{mn}{d}=\text{lcd}(m,n)$; 
notice that $m \mid D$ and $m \mid D$.

---

Then for every element $a=(b,c) \in \mathbb{Z}_n \bigoplus \mathbb{Z}_m$ 
we have: 
$$ 
\underbrace{(b,c)+ (b,c) + ... + (b,c)}_{D\text{-times}} 
= 
D (b,c)= (Db,Dc) = (0,0) 
; 
$$
so every element of $ \ \ \mathbb{Z}_n \bigoplus \mathbb{Z}_m \ \ $ has order at most equal to $D:=\dfrac{mn}{d}=\text{lcd}(m,n)$.

---

On the otherhand we know that $ 1 \in \mathbb{Z}_{nm}$ has the order equal to $nm$.

---

Now suppose that 
$\mathbb{Z}_n \bigoplus \mathbb{Z}_m$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{nm}$ are **isomorphic**;
then $\mathbb{Z}_n \bigoplus \mathbb{Z}_m$ 
must have an element of order $mn$;
but we know that the order of every element of $\mathbb{Z}_n \bigoplus \mathbb{Z}_m$ is less than or equal to 
$$D:=\dfrac{mn}{d}=\text{lcd}(m,n) ; $$ 
which implies that $D=mn$; equivalently $d=1$.